# Identify bug in leaves?

Tags: identification, plant-health, indoors, bugs

Does anyone know what this is? Will soap water kill this?

Unlike the mealyworms I’ve seen this on the top part of the leaf. It also doesn’t come off easily; you kinda have to scrape it off.

I started spraying it with soapy water today.

Can anyone identify this? Thanks.
[image]

[image]